# How to aggregate two json data with doing maths

Tags: javascript, json

I have two json file one which have contain all team name and code and the second one contain match details and score.i want to make another json which aggregate Total Matches Won-Lost total Goals
json1:https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5d07165d4f234842a566d0b4
json2:https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5d07168c2808a77fb80a2254

i tried to use ... rest operator.

Json 1

```
{
"name": "English Premier League 2011/12",
"clubs": [
{
"key": "chelsea",
"name": "Chelsea",
"code": "CHE"
},
{
"key": "arsenal",
"name": "Arsenal",
"code": "ARS"
},
{
"key": "tottenham",
"name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
"code": "TOT"
}
]
}
```

Json2

```
{
  "name": "English Premier League 2011/12",
  "rounds": [
    {
      "name": "Round 1",
      "matches": [
        {
          "date": "2012-01-11",
          "team1": {
            "key": "tottenham",
            "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "code": "TOT"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "everton",
            "name": "Everton",
            "code": "EVE"
          },
          "score1": 2,
          "score2": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2011-08-15",
          "team1": {
            "key": "mancity",
            "name": "Manchester City",
            "code": "MCI"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "swansea",
            "name": "Swansea",
            "code": "SWA"
          },
          "score1": 4,
          "score2": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2011-08-14",
          "team1": {
            "key": "westbrom",
            "name": "West Bromwich Albion",
            "code": "WBA"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "manutd",
            "name": "Manchester United",
            "code": "MUN"
          },
          "score1": 1,
          "score2": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2011-08-14",
          "team1": {
            "key": "stoke",
            "name": "Stoke City",
            "code": "STK"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "chelsea",
            "name": "Chelsea",
            "code": "CHE"
          },
          "score1": 0,
          "score2": 0
        }
]
}
]
}
```

Expected JSON Result

```
"clubs": [
{
"key": "chelsea",
"name": "Chelsea",
"code": "CHE",
"total_matches":38,
"won":"21",
"lost":"15",
"ties":"2",
"total-goals":"33",
"scored-against":"28"

},
{
"key": "arsenal",
"name": "Arsenal",
"code": "ARS",
"total_matches":38,
"won":"21",
"lost":"15",
"ties":"2",
"total-goals":"33",
"scored-against":"28"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this might help you need to add extra error checking and few modifications to get the exact result.

```js
let a = {
    "name": "English Premier League 2011/12",
    "clubs": [{
            "key": "chelsea",
            "name": "Chelsea",
            "code": "CHE"
        },
        {
            "key": "arsenal",
            "name": "Arsenal",
            "code": "ARS"
        },
        {
            "key": "tottenham",
            "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "code": "TOT"
        }
    ]
}
let b = {
    "name": "English Premier League 2011/12",
    "rounds": [{
        "name": "Round 1",
        "matches": [{
                "date": "2012-01-11",
                "team1": {
                    "key": "tottenham",
                    "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                    "code": "TOT"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "key": "everton",
                    "name": "Everton",
                    "code": "EVE"
                },
                "score1": 2,
                "score2": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2011-08-15",
                "team1": {
                    "key": "mancity",
                    "name": "Manchester City",
                    "code": "MCI"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "key": "swansea",
                    "name": "Swansea",
                    "code": "SWA"
                },
                "score1": 4,
                "score2": 0
            },
            {
                "date": "2011-08-14",
                "team1": {
                    "key": "westbrom",
                    "name": "West Bromwich Albion",
                    "code": "WBA"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "key": "manutd",
                    "name": "Manchester United",
                    "code": "MUN"
                },
                "score1": 1,
                "score2": 2
            },
            {
                "date": "2011-08-14",
                "team1": {
                    "key": "stoke",
                    "name": "Stoke City",
                    "code": "STK"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "key": "chelsea",
                    "name": "Chelsea",
                    "code": "CHE"
                },
                "score1": 0,
                "score2": 0
            }
        ]
    }]
}
let teamCodes = a.clubs.map(e => e['code']);
console.log("Team codes");
console.log(teamCodes)
let output = {'clubs': []};
teamCodes.map(e=> output.clubs.push({"code": e}))
b.rounds[0].matches.map(ef => {
    var total_matches = 0
    var won  = 0
    var lost = 0
    var tie  = 0
    var total_goals = 0
    teamCodes.forEach(function(e, index){
        var codeIndex = output.clubs.findIndex(function(element, index, array){return element.code ===e})
            
        if(ef.team1.code == e){            
            output.clubs[codeIndex].code = e
            output.clubs[codeIndex].name = ef.team1.name;
            output.clubs[codeIndex].key = ef.team1.key;
            output.clubs[codeIndex].total_matches = total_matches + 1
            output.clubs[codeIndex].total_goals = total_goals + ef.score1
            if(ef.score1 > ef.score2) {
                output.clubs[codeIndex].won = won + 1
            } else if(ef.score1 < ef.score2) {
                output.clubs[codeIndex].lost = lost + 1
            } else {
                output.clubs[codeIndex].tie = tie + 1
            }


        } else if(ef.team2.code == e) {
            output.clubs[codeIndex].code = e
            output.clubs[codeIndex].name = ef.team2.name;
            output.clubs[codeIndex].key = ef.team2.key;
            output.clubs[codeIndex].total_matches = total_matches + 1
            output.clubs[codeIndex].total_goals = total_goals + ef.score2
            if(ef.score1 > ef.score2) {
                output.clubs[codeIndex].won = won + 1
            } else if(ef.score1 < ef.score2) {
                output.clubs[codeIndex].lost = lost + 1
            } else {
                output.clubs[codeIndex].tie = tie + 1
            }
        }
    })
})
console.log("Output")
console.dir(output)
```